# PHP GET request but no ?=

Tags: php

I am trying to find out how websites like Imgur, MEGA and such are able to do this:
`https://imgur.com/a/SbmNz` (emphasis on `SbmNz`)

The `SbmNz` bit is dynamic between images or files and I guess it is a kind of `$_GET`. And I was just wondering how you can do this without the usual `?name=value` way.

Comment: with a rewrite rule in the htaccess file it is trivially easy

Answer (score 0):

you can use any MVC or just write a htaccess rule for it , for instance, you can use laravel to pass variables along with url 
for laravel refer [URL Generation-Laravel5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/urls)
to write .htaccess refer [USING .HTACCESS REWRITE RULES](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with Apache rewriting module by changing `.htaccess` (Create `.htaccess` file in your folder)

For example if you have this snippet

```
RewriteRule ^play/([^/]*)$ player.php?id=$1 [L]
```

When user visits [www.example.com/play/Trg4](http://www.example.com/play/Trg4) in backend request is actually handled for [www.example.com/player.php?id=Trg4](http://www.example.com/player.php?id=Trg4)

Then you can get the `id` with `$_GET['id']`. it means there is no change with php code. it is completely done with `.htaccess`

Make sure you enabled `rewrite_module` of your Apache server